# when can you join a varchar to an nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to understand when a join between a varchar and nvarchar works and when it does not.

Brief background: We will be changing many of our varchar columns to nvarchar columns.  We also have dozens of SSRS reports with a total of 100 queries or so.  I need to assess the risk of the change - hopefully to avoid excessive testing.

(I do recognize that joins should not be done on varchar columns in the first place, but that's a different problem for a different day...)

I have anecdotally noticed problems with varchar to nvarcher joins in the past, using COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT to solve the problem, but I cannot seem to recreate such issues with just a simple join between the two data types.

When does this mismatch cause a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, joining varchar and nvarchar columns 'just works', with the following important caveats that generally boil down to "...but you shouldn't do it if you can avoid it":

1) Mismatching varchar/nvarchar in queries and joins can cause huge performance issues. Because the database has to basically perform a function on one side of the JOIN or WHERE clause comparison to convert from one type to the other in order to compare or match them, it can cause table scans even when there are apparently appropriate indexes available. It is absolutely recommended that any columns that are compared in WHERE clauses or joined in JOIN clauses be of the same fundamental type.

2) The type mismatch error you mention generally happens when referencing temp tables when the collation of the column in the database is not the same as the collation that was selected when SQL Server was installed.  This is because temp tables are created in 'tempdb', which has the default collation used by the server itself. I've adopted a policy that any time a temp table is used, every varchar/nvarcher column should be declared with a COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, so that the collation it is created with matches the default collation of the database, not the default collation of tempdb.  This eliminates the errors, and also ensures proper index selection if you put indexes on the temp table and use the columns in a WHERE or JOIN (see above).

Comment: Fantastic - I learned more than I thought I would!  Many thanks!